# How do you know if a Pytorch Save contains a model and/or just the weights?

Tags: pytorch

I'm fairly new to pytorch and this might be a version issue, but I see torch.load and torch.load_state_dict used, but in both cases the file extension is commonly ".pth"

Models that I have created, I can Save and Load them via torch.Save and torch.Load and call model.eval()

I have another model file that I'm fairly sure is just the state dictionary, as model.eval() fails after a load.

How would I inspect the file and know that one has a full model in it?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a foolproof way to figure this out. `torch.save` uses Python's pickle under the hood (ref: [Pytorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/serialization.html#saving-loading-tensors)), so users can save arbitrary Python objects. For example, the following code wraps the state dicts in a dictionary:

```
# example from https://github.com/lucidrains/lightweight-gan/blob/fce20938562a0cc289c915f7317722a8241abd37/lightweight_gan/lightweight_gan.py#L1437
save_data = {
    'GAN': self.GAN.state_dict(),
    'version': __version__,
    'G_scaler': self.G_scaler.state_dict(),
    'D_scaler': self.D_scaler.state_dict()
}
torch.save(save_data, self.model_name(num))
```

If it helps, state dicts themselves are `OrderedDict` objects. If `isinstance(model, collections.OrderedDict)` returns True, you can be fairly confident that `model` is a state dict. (Remember to `import collections`)

Models themselves are subclasses of `torch.nn.Module`, so you can check if something is a model by verifying that `isinstance(model, torch.nn.Module)` returns True.

Comment: I agree, it looks like the only way is to try and load it, and if it fails to load you have to manually inspect it